# Android: findViewById returns null for view inside nested Relative Layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to get a reference to a `TextView`, but it returns a `null` object. This is the `xml` file with the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't mind the lack of alignment etc, I removed what's irrelevant for this. I tried doing it the way I normally do (I should mention this is for a list item) like this:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

When that didn't work I did some research and realized that I might need to call find them from within the specific layout like this:

```
RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.relative1);
TextView textView1 = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

But this didn't work either, and I cannot seem to find any other way to solve the problem.

Comment: Dear just try without giving the reference of "rel" and it will work fine

Comment: Did you call setContentView() first?

Comment: Post your activity class.

Comment: yes, it is necessary to call setContentView first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean the project...
Build -> Clean Project

Comment: Would you like to share the reason to clean the project ?

Comment: There is an IDE generated source code file called "R.java", which contains all the ID's for the Resources an Views. If you clean the project, this file gets deleted and it will be generated again, but with the updated views.